# cucumber table diff regardless row order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, bdd

is there any way to tell a cucumber table's diff! method, that I don't care about the row order?

Example:
The feature says:

```
| start | eat | left |
|  12   |  5  |  7   |
|  20   |  5  |  15  |
```

The code outputs

```
| start | eat | left |
|  20   |  5  |  15  |
|  12   |  5  |  7   |
```

which is ok for me. Cucumber would fail nonetheless, because it also checks for the order (which is nice in most cases).

Couldn't find a solution for it :(

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can sort the rows in both tables (the test value and the tested value) in a way ensuring a unique order.

Comment: that's the way, i'm solving it now. but i have another project, where this approach is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

I would have expected that there is a corresponding ruby version of the  following Java method:

```
cucumber.api.DataTable#unorderedDiff(cucumber.api.DataTable)
```

This is under cucumber-core artifact.